# MVC load Partial View data when it is called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal, partial-views

I am developing an `MVC Bootstrap` Application.

I have a Parent View, that calls a `Modal Bootstrap Partial View`. That Partial View is loaded when User clicks a buttom.

The `Partial View` calls `Controller` Method that goes to the server.

Here is my example. In my `Parent View` a have this call.

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalRecomendIt" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/UploadSearch/_RecomendIt.cshtml");
</div>
```

Inside the Partial View I have something like this.

```html
 <div class="modal-body">
     <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.Action("GetUsers", "Users")
     </div>
  </div>
```

It Works fine...

The problem I found is that The `Controller Method` I call in `Partial View` is called when `Parent View` is loaded. So it takes too long to render.

What I need is to call those methods when `Partial View` is called.

Is it posible?

Thanks..

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: One way could be to use AJAX to get the partial view HTML on button click and insert it into the appropriate spot on your parent view.

Comment: you want display the partial view.when the parent view is loaded, am i right?